# SQLite: Multiple Table Join

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple one two many relationship.

There are three tables

Main:

```
ID TITLE
________
1  Peter
2  Lars
```

Orders:

```
SKU MAIN_ID
___________
RFX 1
HNI 2
RRP 2
```

Tools:

```
NAME  MAIN_ID
____________
FORK  1
KNIFE 1
SPOON 2
```

So orders and tools hava a `MAIN_ID` which refers to the Main table. 
So Peter has the order RFX and the tools FORK and SPOON
Lars has the orders HNI and RRP and the tool SPOON.

How can I do a single query to find out which orders and tools peter has and which ones lars has?
I tried it with an inner join but then there are duplicate entries.

Comment: A SELECT query returns a single table with a fixed number of columns. Show the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `group_concat()` to get the values in one row.  However, you need to pre-aggregate the data before the `join`:

```
select m.*, o.skus, t.tools
from main m join
     (select main_id, group_concat(sku) as skus
      from orders
      group by main_id
     ) o
     on o.main_id = m.id join
     (select main_id, group_concat(name) as tools
      from tools
      group by main_id
     ) t
     on t.main_id = m.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just included it [here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/commit/a73bf6483d35fc8ccd58e18d10f4753e5905b696#diff-4d145ba083e121890666ca7bc25b5a98R51) (this example was an abstraction on the problem.)